# Count number of days between multiple dates based on measure and sum each week

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So, strange one to explain...

I have a table with the start dates of each person in project (each start day is the first Monday of the week)

I want to know how many people were in the project on any given week.

If I select two weeks in a slicer, for example

Week1
Week3

And there were 10 people in week 1 and 30 in week 3 the total should be 40.

How do I build a measure to do this.

Essentially I'm asking it to count the number of rows(project members) where the start date is >= each selected date and sum each individual result.

I hope this has made sense unable to share much due to work red tape

Thanks

Lloyd

Comment: Show some sample data.

Comment: whats the format of your calendar table does it have a week column? - not essential but it would be easier to do using a calculcate method (assuming the relationships are correct between the tables) but echoing R_R add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the following way:

1. Create a bin for the work week
2. Create a measure to count the bin from step 1.